# Why does my uploaded file show a size of zero?

Tags: php

Hello I am trying to check the size of a file in PHP but it does not seem to work. My input page is

```
<html>
<title>File Upload</title>
<body>
<h1>
Upload Files
</h1>
<form action = "yes.php" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Upload your file
<input type = "file" name = "file" id = "fileToUpload">
<input type ="submit" name ="submit" value = "Start Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the yes.php

```
<?php
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
 echo "$filename";
 echo "\n$filesize";
 if ($filesize < 4) {
  echo "good";
 } else {
  echo "bad";
 }
}
?>
```

It outputs

```
disc.mp4 0good
```

The file `disc.mp4` is 5.8 MB but it returns as 0 MB even when it correctly identifies the name of the file. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to SO - a 2 second google search for `get php filesize`  also gives you the answer you seek.

Comment: If there was a function called `filesize` that would be unbelievable!

Comment: PHP is telling you the uploaded file has a size of 0 so you'll need to trust it on that. It all points to a failed upload. What does `$_FILES["file"]["error"]` contain?

Answer (score 0):

The different keys of the `$_FILES` array are explained [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Your code is taking for granted that every script invocation contains a valid file upload, which of course if often untrue: just open `yes.php` in your browser and you'll see (or you should see) lots of error messages. You're also making a strange check: the upload is valid if the file size is 0 to 3 bytes :-!

The bare minimum you need is:

1. Accommodate the fact that `$_FILES['file']` may or may not exist.
2. Verify whether the upload succeeded.
3. If you expect a 5.8 MB file, don't require it to have an arbitrary smaller size.

Following you code style, I'd be something like:

```
<?php
$error = $_FILES["file"]["error"] ?? null;
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"] ?? null;
$filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"] ?? null;
$expected_size = 5.8 * 1024 * 1024; # Assuming you want to enforce this for some reason
if ($error === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo "$filename";
    echo "\n$filesize";
    if ($filesize != $expected_size) {
        echo "good";
    } else {
        echo "bad";
    }
} elseif($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
    echo "upload failed";
}
```